# How to check if 3 columns of a pandas dataframe are equal to a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 5 different columns, say A,B,C,D, E. I'd like to find rows where `A` and `B` are equal to `a` and `b`. I want to see if there is any way to write this condition as follows

```
 df[df['A','B'] == ('a','b')]
```

Comment: So col A should equal "a" and col B should equal "b"? Also, where's the 3rd column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the query close to what you showed to us

```
df[df[['A','B']].apply(tuple,axis=1)==('a','b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[(df['A'] == 'a') & (df['B'] == 'b')]
```

This will return a DataFrame with only rows where `df['A'] == 'a'` and `df['B'] == 'b'`